# different background color for sender and reciever in private inbox

Tags: php, mysql, css

I made a simple static private message script in php and i want different color background for sender's and receiver's message

```
$sql="SELECT  message,timestamp from pm WHERE (from_user='".$_SESSION["username"]."' OR from_user='$touser') AND (to_user='$touser' OR to_user='".$_SESSION["username"]."') ORDER BY timestamp";
                        $ex=$conn->prepare($sql);
                        $ex->execute();
                        while($result=$ex->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                echo "<div class='message-view'>";

                                echo "<p class='subject'>".$result["message"]."</p>";

                                echo "</div>";
                            }
```

the pm table has the following attributes (id,to_user,from_user,subject,message,timestamp)

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: can you post the generated code?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/otycffqsn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
$sql="SELECT  message,timestamp from pm WHERE (from_user='".$_SESSION["username"]."' OR from_user='$touser') AND (to_user='$touser' OR to_user='".$_SESSION["username"]."') ORDER BY timestamp";
```

to

```
$sql="SELECT  message,timestamp,from_user  from pm WHERE (from_user='".$_SESSION["username"]."' OR from_user='$touser') AND (to_user='$touser' OR to_user='".$_SESSION["username"]."') ORDER BY timestamp";
```

and then check during while specific class depending on who was a sender:

```
if ($result['from_user'] == $_SESSION["username"])
    echo '<div class="message-view-sender" style="background-color: yellow;">';
else
    echo "<div class='message-view'>";
```

Comment: Yeah, adding the following if condition did the trick, thank you!

if($result['from_user']==$_SESSION["username"])

Comment: no problem. just please choose it as a right answer (: